# Encrypting War files

Tags: java, security, encryption

I would like to encrypt or obfuscate my WAR file so that reverse engineering will take a little more effort.  Is there such a tool or maven plugin that will encrypt a WAR file and its contents?

Also, once the WAR is encrypted, how will the Web Application be deployed at that point?  If the web server explodes the WAR, can each jar and resource still be encrypted, how will the startup behavior be modified to decrypt the nested jars and resources?

Thanks,
Walter

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If someone is interested in your code, he will be able to reconstruct it anyways, as long as he access to the binary (in this case a war). In Java that is especially simple, but it is also possible for C. Interested in your code may be only developers, with little effort they gain the knowledge needed for this. So the extra-effort to obfuscate your code may fend only very few hackers off. I can't see the benefit.

Comment: +1 for @Mnementh's comments. What is the objective here? You are deploying your war in a web application container (e.g. Tomcat), sever-side. Web clients will not have access to it.

Comment: I'm not worried about people viewing the site in firefox or whatever, but other people on the system or if developing a website for a client and using their servers, I may or may not want them to easily have access to the source code.

Comment: I suppose the best solution would be to just go with private hosting then.

Comment: @WalterWhite Walter, I am trying to figure out the same thing (how to avoid client to see the source code). Were you able to come up with a nice solution other than private hosting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Cracking Java byte-code encryption - Why Java obfuscation schemes based on byte-code encryption won't work](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-05/01-qa-0509-jcrypt.html) - Article from JavaWorld.

If your code is important enough to go to all this trouble it probably makes sense to host it on a private server... :\

Comment: private hosting appears to be the best option

Comment: Your link says "Page not found". Probably owner removed the article

Answer (score 4):

[DashO](http://www.preemptive.com/dasho-for-java.html) from PreEmptive Solutions will also obfuscate WAR files.

Comment: would you please tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

[Zelix KlassMaster](http://www.zelix.com/klassmaster/features.html) can be run from Ant.  Looks like it handles [WARs](http://www.zelix.com/klassmaster/docs/openStatement.html) too.

Couldn't tell you about the deployment of the WAR but any obfuscator that causes an archive not to work after it's been obfuscated isn't worth much.

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem here. 
I tried it with Yguard 2.4, Proguard 4.7, Zelix 5.4.6, Allatori 4.0 , JavaGuard 1.0, Sandmark 3.40. All of those are not giving me glance that my obfuscated web application would not run. They can obfuscate bytecodes even they can obfuscate my application. That is all.

p.s : The application server(server container tomcat, apache, glassfish, weblogic , websphere etc) can't hide our code from hackers. in my experience all of them has temp folder which contains currently using items. In this folder we can see the code.

Finally i would say if we use Java then we make opensource. :P

Answer (score 0):

I had a solution to this problem. It goes like this:

Encrypt a war file. Like ZIP it and encrypt it, so it cannot be read without the password.

Set up a system, or only give the password to a hosting service. Once you and a client
have worked out your terms, you give the password to the hosting service. They decrypt the
war file and install it. They client only sees the website/api. The client never has 
access to your jar files.

Any comments?