# How to check if someone tries to share your program

Tags: java, encryption, sharing

I made a program *(.jar)* which I want to let others use, but not share with others without my permission. I thought about encryption, but I know they will just let the other people know the encryption password.

Is there any way in **Java or Javascript** ***Offline***  to check if someone attempts to share my program? or better yet a way to stop people from sharing, but allowing me to share (one time share or password to share)

Edit: prefer offline as i know how to do a online database solution

Comment: I hope you have to obfuscate the code using progurad, retrogurad etc...It will obfuscate your code but it allows to extract you classes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466424/making-commercial-java-software-drm

Comment: Even the biggest software companies mostly achieve this by legal rather than technological means.

Comment: What does this program do exactly? Could you perhaps move a crucial part of it to a server with user authentication? That's not exactly offline though, but that's how it's mostly done today I think.

Comment: Well from the looks of it a online way with a database and a key will be the best solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can ask their IP address and use that as a key then build a Jar file based on that. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Good idea, but i might work with people who are either not good with computers or do not want to give me their IP address

Comment: IPv4? Around 32 bits shouldn't be too hard to brute force.