# Are there tools for code obfuscation for Scala?

Tags: scala

Are there tools for code obfuscation for Scala?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java Code obfuscation actually effective vs decompilers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242055/is-java-code-obfuscation-actually-effective-vs-decompilers)

Comment: how do you figure this is a duplicate of that question?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Scala compiles into JVM bytecode, for which there are tons of obfuscators like [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)
or [yGuard](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yguard_about.html)

Comment: I'll even add that there's a plugin for ProGuard in SBT, which makes obfuscation very easy. :-)

Answer (score 34):

Use Scalaz. :-P

Comment: I'd give you +2 if I could.